# Xcode 7.1 iPad PRO simulator stretching iPad Air 2 app?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, xcode7

Today I updated from Xcode 7.0.1 to 7.1.1 just for iPad Pro simulator. The iPad Pro resolution is different from all other iPads so is the iPad Pro simulator just stretching my game to fit into iPad Pro? The iPad Pro simulator, my app doesn't have a stretched look though it looks great. I'm confused, is the simulator just playing a stretched version of iPad Air 2 or if I were to use iPad Pro device and run the app, i'd see also a perfectly fitted iPad Pro app running?

The iPad PRO is loading the code from iPad AIR, iPad AIR 2 and iPad RETINA simulators

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone still having above issues here's the solution I found:

In AppDelegate.m, in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code, use the following code:

```
 if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 1366))

{


    UIStoryboard *iPadPRO = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadPRO" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPadPRO instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

else  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){


        UIStoryboard *iPadRetina = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadRetina" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPadRetina instantiateInitialViewController];

        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   



    }
```